# Problem with comparing made-up objects with equals method

Tags: java, object, equals

I'm trying to make a program that compares object archive to an Arraylist archives and only add it to the arraylist if it isn't in it, but am really struggling. I've tried modifying the for loop, to adding a new boolean to check if there is there is already an identical archive but just can't seem to get it to only add unique archives. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayList<Archive> archives = new ArrayList<>();
        while (true) {
            System.out.println("Identifier? (empty will stop)");
            String identifier = scanner.nextLine();
            if (identifier.isEmpty()) {
                break;
            }
            System.out.println("Name? (empty will stop)");
            String name = scanner.nextLine();
            if (name.isEmpty()) {
                break;
            }
            Archive archive = new Archive(identifier, name);

            boolean contains = false;
            for (int i = 0; i < archives.size(); i++) {
                if (archive.equals(archives.get(i))) {
                    contains = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (contains == false) {
                archives.add(archive);
            }
        }

        for (Archive i : archives) {
            System.out.println(i.getIdentifier() + ": " + i.getName());
        }
    }
}



public class Archive {

    private String identifier;
    private String name;

    public Archive(String identifier, String name) {
        this.identifier = identifier;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getIdentifier() {
        return this.identifier;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public boolean equals(Archive archive, Object compared) {

        if (compared == archive) {
            return true;
        }
        if (!(compared instanceof Archive)) {
            return false;
        }

        Archive compare = (Archive) compared;
        if (compare.getIdentifier().equals(archive.getIdentifier()) && compare.getName().equals(archive.getName())) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

}
```

//Also just realised that instead of the whole for loop with boolean contains thing I can just do

```
if(archives.contains(archive){
contains=true;}
```

Comment: You are not overriding the equals method. You created a new one that is never used.

Comment: This is an excellent example of why to always use `@Override`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The signature of equals method is wrong. 
It should be

```
public boolean equals(Object compared) {
    if(compared==null || !(compared instanceof Archive)){
        return false;
    }

    Archive compare = (Archive) compared;
    if (compare.getIdentifier().equals(this.getIdentifier()) && compare.getName().equals(this.getName())) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Ah I see thanks so much! I was wondering since in my original equals method it requires 2 parameters (Archive and Object), why did the program even run when in the Main program I only put in 1 parameter (archives.get(i))?

Comment: Because it will use default equals method of Object class. We need to override it for custom checks.